# gitlab and nginxX failing with error 403

Tags: ruby, git, nginx, gitlab

I got an minor Problem with Gitlab.
I setup the complete system according to the manual from gitlab.
I used an nginx xserver with theire nginx config file.
If I access any none php file it works.
But as soon as I open one of these files I get ofllowing line in the server log:

```
2013/12/04 14:24:46 [error] 28622#0: *10 access forbidden by rule, client: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd, server: xxx.xxxx.xxx, request: "GET /dev/worker/blob/master/call.php HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.xxxx.xxx", referrer: "https://xxx.xxxx.xxx/dev/worker/tree/master"
```

I'm accessing the server over https.
Internaly it runs on http

I also have installed php-fpm but it does not run on the current host.
Please help

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the nginx configuration itself.
I have an ispconfig panel running that creates the nginx site files.
Problem was, it creates an entry that disallows php files to everyone.
It makes sence for php based sites, as the php files can only be accessed through the fpm process.
But it makes no sence for a git server
^^

thanks for the patience